# can i update IP address of recipients to DOCUSIGN through API

Tags: docusignapi

I am getting information from client through internal portal and sending the request for envelope creation (along with details from client) from Server.

Everything is fine.

But the problem is with AUDIT history.

in the Audit history the IP address information is all SERVER information as server is the source for sending REST request.

But in my case Client is the one who provided the details.

I am trying to see if I can send the CLient IP address in the REST API so that it will inline with the actual events.

is this possible or reference to any achievable way is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to set the Client IP address via REST API.  The information recorded to the Envelope Audit Trail is based upon data collected by DocuSign throughout the envelope's history. The fact that DocuSign records data exactly as it truly occurs is what gives credibility to the Audit Trail information, and therefore I wouldn't expect DocuSign to ever allow any of the Audit Trail properties to be set explicity via an API call.  (Doing so would open the door to fraud, as an integrated application could use the API to falsify information in an envelope's audit trail.)

Answer (score 3):

Are you referring to Embedded Signing?

All entries are not changeable.

The Envelope is being created by your server, so you will not be able to change that.

You'll have the client's IP when they enter their signature.

See screenshot below for the web version of this info for a test document.

[image]